# Stage Failure Error

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have the following code:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\Desktop\\Data 2014")
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\Desktop\\Spark-1.4.1\\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6")
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0" "sparkr-shell"')



   .libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths())) 
    library(SparkR)
    library(magrittr)
    sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local")
    sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
```

When I run the following:

```
data <- read.df(sqlContext, "Test.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

`Test.csv`  is only a  `3 x 2`  table.

Comment: are you sure of your spark path ?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the more details and cause of the error you are getting in the below link. https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/javaionotserializableexception.html

You have to give the full path of the csv file,if the file in not in your present working directory.I have not much idea. Below I have pasted the code. It is working fine for me you can try it.

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME='/home/jayashree/spark-1.5.0')  # the path of spark_home dir. Please change it according to your spark home path
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'), 'R', 'lib'), .libPaths()))

library(SparkR)

sc <- sparkR.init(master="local", sparkPackages="com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0") 

sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

data <- read.df(sqlContext, "/full_path/to_your/datafile.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true")
```

Are you working on windows?